# Issue with SwiftUI Picker filtering when conditionals are present within the View body

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

#### Problem

I am running into an issue when attempting to filter content within a picker. The logic works as expected when there are no conditionals living within the View body; however, upon the introduction of the conditionals, the binding of the underlying data becomes decoupled from the view.

#### Repro

By uncommenting the `if true` closure in `DemoView`, you will observe the inability to visualize the filtering of the picker options; however, the underlying data changes.

#### Workaround

Naturally a workaround is building a bespoke `SearchPicker`, but I am curious if anyone has an explanation as to why the conditionals break the data binding.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    let allCountries: [String]
    let allSubjects: [SubjectOption]
    @State private var countrySearch = ""
    @State private var subjectSearch = ""
    @State private var countrySelection: String?
    @State private var subjectSelection: SubjectOption?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
//            if true {
                Section {
                    Picker("Country", selection: $countrySelection) {
                        SearchBar(text: $countrySearch, placeholder: "Search...")
                        ForEach(filteredCountries, id: \.self) { country in
                            Text(country)
                                .tag(country as String?)
                        }
                    }
                    Picker("Subject", selection: $subjectSelection) {
                        SearchBar(text: $subjectSearch, placeholder: "Search...")
                        ForEach(filteredSubjects) { option in
                            Text(option.name)
                                .tag(option as SubjectOption?)
                        }
                    }
                }
//            }
        }
    }
    
    private var filteredCountries: [String] {
        countrySearch.isEmpty ? allCountries : allCountries.filter { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(countrySearch) }
    }
    
    private var filteredSubjects: [SubjectOption] {
        subjectSearch.isEmpty ? allSubjects : allSubjects.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(subjectSearch) }
    }
}

struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DemoView(allCountries: sampleCountries, allSubjects: sampleSubjects)
                .navigationTitle("Picker Demo")
        }
    }
    
    static let sampleCountries: [String] = [
        "Brazil",
        "Canada",
        "Egypt",
        "France",
        "Germany",
        "United Kingdom"
    ]
    
    static let sampleSubjects: [SubjectOption] = [
        .init(id: "0", name: "Physics"),
        .init(id: "1", name: "Math"),
        .init(id: "2", name: "Biology"),
        .init(id: "3", name: "English"),
        .init(id: "4", name: "Foreign Language"),
        .init(id: "5", name: "Chemistry")
    ]
}
```

```
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar,
                      context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,
                       textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SubjectOption: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```